# unable to conditionally revalue a variable

Tags: r, plyr

So I am trying to conditionally revalue characters in a column (example: if the value is "1" - change it to "pre-treatment", if it is "2" - "post-treatment".

I have researched this online, and it seems like

```
simon$Session <- revalue(simon$Session, c("1" = "pre", "2" = "post"))
```

should have worked fine, but instead I am getting this error

```
Error in revalue(simon$Session, c(`1` = "pre", `2` = "post")) : 
  x is not a factor or a character vector
```

I have plyr library loaded.

This seems to be a super easy issue but somehow I am having hard time figuring out what the problem is. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `simon$Session` is not a factor or character vector. Looking at the documentation `?revlalue` we see that the function only works on characters and vectors.

Try doing

```
revalue(as.character(simon$Session), c(`1` = "pre", `2` = "post"))
```

An alternative is to use `recode` from dplyr.

```
simon %>% mutate(value = recode(Session,`1` = "pre", `2` = "post"))
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response! I tried that and got the error  ```Error: unexpected '=' in "revalue(as.character(simon$Session), c(1=" ```

Comment: ```revalue``` worked once quotations  were added to 1 and 2. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Alina you should mark it as an answer if it resolved your issue.